# SQLite and STRFTIME

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sqlite, qsqlquery

in my SQLite database, I have a time field with minutes, seconds, and centiseconds:

```
 00:01:100
```

I want to select the row with the MAX value in milliseconds and I fount the **strftime** function. I'm trying with:

```
  SELECT MAX(strftime("%M:%S:%SSS", field)) FROM table;
```

But it doesn't works.

Comment: Um It doesn't work because you can't just make up time formats. There's no provision for centiseconds to be stored like that. Their stored like decimals http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html <- This lists allowd formats

Comment: 100 centiseconds is normally treated as 1 second; did you mean milliseconds?

Comment: Just use MAX() without strftime(). What do you think it does?

Comment: MAX in that field, doesn't works.

Answer (score 2):

Because this isn't in the list of allowed formats, you have to first edit it so that it's supported.

Then run the `strftime` function

```
SELECT MAX(strftime("%H:%M:%f", "00:" || substr(field,1,3) || replace(':','.',substr(field,4)))) FROM table;
```

This <del>should</del> will not work

---

**EDIT**

So, Update. Why it doesn't work:

`strftime` is useful when you already have the time in a format and you want to convert it to another format.

You have the item in a non-supported format. ([List of formats here](http://sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html)). So, you have it saved probably in the default TEXT format.

So, now you need to write a query that takes this text converts it to the correct format and compares it. You basically kind of have to write your own maximization function, that will convert this text into something the `MAX` function can handle.

This is done with a combination of substrings and casting. What I've done in the query below is cast the substrings as integers, multiply them to convert them to seconds and then add it to the `MAX`.

```
SELECT time,MAX(cast(substr(time,1,2) as integer)*60+cast(substr(time,4,2) as integer )+cast(substr(time,7,3) as integer)/100) FROM t;
```

Here's an example of it running

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/1c665/1

Comment: @helloimyourmind. I went back and checked a BUNCH of things. Finally got a running example with an SQLFiddle link to it